# Mediator pattern between ViewModels and Views in different libraries

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mediator

I'm italian, so sorry for bad language.

I'm working on a MVVM based application. My solution includes in an single WPF application project Ms, Vs and VMs.
As mediator between Views and ViewModels I use a Messenger class with Register and NotifyColleagues methods, created as a property o the Application class.

All this worked fine until now, that I decided to divide Ms, Vs and VMs in different libraries.
In this scenario, the Messenger class can no longer be put in the Application class of the executable, beacause it would not be possible for libraries to get in contact with it.

So what should I do? Is there a different mediator pattern, more suitable for my case, or am I missing something?

thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to craft any specific pattern implementation when working with Views and ViewModels. That interaction should leverage the framework binding features, the View binding to the ViewModel. You can avoid any coupling if approached properly.

If you want to inject the ViewModel into the View at run-time for further decoupling; you can certainly do that and should leverage a DI framework such as [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/).

When cross module communication surfaces; you can use the [Event Aggregator](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) pattern which [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) offers an implementation of.

Comment: there's no real need for EventAggregator: the author can use his Mediator with MEF or Unity without problems.

Comment: @stijn The OPs mediator pattern implementation could certainly work; I leverage frameworks when possible. If the OP looks into Prism, leveraging the EventAggregator is trivial.